# powerbi embedded - access token with 2fa on

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-embedded

can i generate a powerbi embed token from my application if i have 2fa turned on?

I don't see anything about this in their documentation.

Can I generate a 1 time perm. embed token without code?

Comment: Instead of user account with multi-factor authentication, you should [authenticate with a service principal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/developer/embedded/embed-service-principal).

Comment: but I want to use a master account, so it's just 1 account that will control everything.  why is a service principal better?

Comment: Because MFA doesn't allow you to login without someone confirming the login on their mobile phone for example.

Comment: yea, but then i'd have to set up all these users in power bi, which i don't want to

Comment: @AndreyNikolov is it possible to generate a password for master user that expires very infrequently, like 1 time a year.

Comment: I can't even get this link to generate a token for me outside of my application. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/embed-token/reports-generate-token-for-create-in-group#code-try-0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. you must turn off 2fa to get pbi access token via code when using master user (because it's just a background user authenticating to power bi - not the  real user who logged in - and therefore there is no opportunity for interaction (prompt to enter pw from text)
2. give the master user very little permissions in general, since it's a little less secure way of doing things.  and store credentials in azure key vault not in some config file.
3. can test it out here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/embed-token/reports-generate-token-in-group#code-try-0.
   parameters: reportId and groupId . Body:

   {"accessLevel" : "View", "allowSaveAs" : "false", "datasetId" :"some id, but doesn't matter unless you create report", "identities":[], "lifetimeInMinutes" : 1000000000}

-- here it doesn't matter if 2fa is on or off obviously